# extract max records details from query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I need to extract all details of table where MAX transaction date for Dealer. Following are tables.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1, ( 
    SELECT Dealer, MAX([Last Transaction]) as LastTransaction
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Dealer
) sq
WHERE Table1.Dealer = sq.Dealer AND Table1.[Last Transaction] = sq.LastTransaction
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is a correlated subquery:

```
select i.*
from input as i
where i.last_transaction = (select max(i2.last_transaction)
                            from input as i2
                            where i2.dealer = i.dealer
                           );
```